# Comparing Arrays using LINQ in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I've two arrays like

```
string[] a = { "a", "b", "c" };
string[] b = { "a", "b", "c" };
```

I need to compare the two arrays using LINQ.

The comparison should take place only if both arrays have same size. The data can be in any order and still return true if all values of a[] and all values of b[] are the same.

Comment: from x in a from y in b where x == y select x == y

but its not correct... can not store in a Boolean variable

Comment: Does each array have unique values?
When you consider two arrays to be the same? if they have the same elements? the same elements in the same order?

Comment: Are you looking for a single bool answer if the two are perfectly the same or are you looking for a check to see if each element is the same as its partner.

Comment: not in same order... but two arrays should have equal size

Comment: i need a single bool answer....

Comment: So comparing { "a", "b", "c" } to { "b", "a", "c" } would return true?

Comment: are these equals? { "a", "a", "b" } , { "a", "b", "b" }
are these equals? { "a", "b", "a" } , { "a", "a", "b" }

Comment: @ Itay : It can not be equal. because both are having different items( in count). The items need not be in same order but there should be exactly one item. For example {"a","a","b"} and {"a","b","a"} are equal

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
string[] a = { "a", "b" };
string[] b = { "a", "b" };

return (a.Length == b.Length && a.Intersect(b).Count() == a.Length);
```

---

After some performance testing:

- Over 10,000 small strings - 5ms
- Over 100,000 small strings - 99ms
- Over 1,000,000 small strings - Avg. 601ms
- Over 100,000 ~500 character strings - 190ms

Comment: but i don't think that performance is ok. intersection is not cheap operation

Comment: @Andrey - It depends on the size of the list as well.

Comment: Syntactically, I'd say `return (a.Length == b.Length && a.Intersect(b).Count() == a.Length)`, but that's just me.

Comment: @Kyle Rozendo: your tests convinced me :)

Comment: @Kyle Rozendo: But wait, is this meeting the OP's requirements? It hasn't been stated explicitly, but I would've assumed the OP is looking for a method to check whether the given arrays have the same elements *in the same order*. Checking `a.Intersect(b).Count()` is only going to ensure they have the same elements, without checking the order.

Comment: @Kyle Rozendo: Never mind, I just noticed the OP's comment where he said they don't have to be in the same order. I'm sold ;)

Comment: However wont this method fail for cases where there are duplicate elements(in both arrays).The intersect operation being a set operation may only retain distinct elements.So if you compare it with Array.length the comparison may fail.

Comment: @joseph - Correct. This will fail where the arrays are identical with duplicates, but there was no request for duplicate control from the OP.

Comment: this will return true even if string[] b = { "b", "a" }; - order of second array changes.

Answer (score 27):

Not sure about the performance, but this seems to work.

```
string[] a = { "a", "b", "c" };
string[] b = { "a", "b", "c" };

bool result = a.SequenceEqual(b);
Assert.AreEqual(true, result);
```

However, it is not order independent so it does not fulfill the OP's requirement.

```
string[] a = { "a", "b", "c" };
string[] b = { "a", "c", "b" };

bool result = a.SequenceEqual(b);
Assert.AreEqual(false, result);
```

Comment: What do you mean, "it is order independant" ? SequenceEqual is NOT order independant. In your second code sample, it will return false

Comment: Not downvoting, but this doesn't answer the question. As per the op: `not in same order... but two arrays should have equal size`

Answer (score 5):

I think this will always be an O(n log n) operation, so I'd just sort both arrays and compare them e.g. using SequenceEqual.

Answer (score 4):

if order doesn't matter or there can be duplicates, then perhaps:

```
public static class IEnumerableExtensions
{
    public static bool HasSameContentsAs<T>(this ICollection<T> source,
                                            ICollection<T> other)
    {
        if (source.Count != other.Count)
        {
            return false;
        }
        var s = source
            .GroupBy(x => x)
            .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());
        var o = other
            .GroupBy(x => x)
            .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());
        int count;
        return s.Count == o.Count &&
               s.All(x => o.TryGetValue(x.Key, out count) &&
                          count == x.Value);
    }
}
```

usage:

```
string[] a = { "a", "b", "c" };
string[] b = { "c", "a", "b" };

bool containSame = a.HasSameContentsAs(b);
```

some use cases:

- different lengths (expect false)

  ```
  string[] a = { "a", "b", "c" };
  string[] b = { "b", "c" };
  ```
- different order (expect true)

  ```
  string[] a = { "a", "b", "c" };
  string[] b = { "b", "c", "a" };
  ```

also works if the inputs can contain duplicate items, though it isn't clear from the question whether that characteristic is desired or not, consider:

- duplicated items have same count (expect true)

  ```
  string[] a = { "a", "b", "b", "c" };
  string[] b = { "a", "b", "c", "b" };
  ```
- duplicated items with different counts (expect false)

  ```
  string[] a = { "a", "b", "b", "b", "c" };
  string[] b = { "a", "b", "c", "b", "c" };
  ```

Comment: If you compare their sizes first would you need to both containsAll operation?

Comment: @Scott, Yes. Consider a = { "a", "b", "c" }; b = { "c", "a". "a" }; same length but the unique items in b are a subset of those in a

Answer (score 4):

This works correctly with duplicates and check each element

```
a.Length == b.Length && !a.Where((t, i) => t != b[i]).Any()
```

Answer (score 3):

```
IDictionary<int, object> a = new Dictionary<int, object>();
IDictionary<int, object> b = new Dictionary<int, object>();
a.Add(1, "1");
a.Add(2, 2);
a.Add(3, "3");

b.Add(3, "3");
b.Add(1, "1");
b.Add(2, 2);

Console.WriteLine(a.All(i => b.Contains(i)) && b.All(i => a.Contains(i)));
```