# How to compare arrays for equality in C#?

Tags: c#, mono

In C++, if you want to check if 2 arrays are equal (in terms of content), you can do:

```
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char * const argv[]) {

  vector<int> a;
  a.push_back(5); 
  a.push_back(6);
  a.push_back(7);

  vector<int> b = a;    // this copies array a's contents to array b

  assert( a == b );     // this compares the content of array a and b one element at a time

  return 0;
}
```

How can I achieve the same thing in C# without writing my own comparison for-loop?

3 links I found so far, though I'm not sure if they are outdated:

- [Jon Skeet's answer](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/246389-comparing-arrays-sounds-easy-but-i-cant-find) (rolling your own loop)
- [Using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2913287/comparing-arrays-using-linq-in-c) (Use SequenceEqual() or Intersect() -- but is this supported in Mono?)
- [MSDN blogs -- Array.Equals](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kathykam/archive/2006/03/08/array-equals.aspx) -- I'm really surprised that comparing array content is not provided out of the box. =S

I'm a C# newbie and I'm using Mono.

Comment: Have you tried LINQ/SequenceEqual/Intersect in Mono? If it works, it's the easy winner.

Comment: @pst You should post an answer and earn them upvotes. :)

Comment: @pst: I tried in MonoDevelop, but the Intellisense didn't popup anything, so it must not be supported.

Comment: what is the exact type of collection that you want to compare ? Is it an IEnumerable ?

Comment: @Gishu: I'm trying to compare Object[] to Object[]. The content is actually just: "A", "B", "C".

Answer (score 3):

```
bool equals = array1.OrderBy(a => a).SequenceEqual(array2.OrderBy(a => a));
```

easy way

Answer (score 1):

i am not sure about MOno that's why i deleted my previous answer

you can do it  by looping through / Stack implementation becoz push/Pop is O(1) operation and accessing an element in array is also O(1) operation.

```
If (Arr1.Length != Arr2.Length)
{
    return false // not equals
}
else
  {
     Arr1.Sort(); // important as both array has to be sorted 
     Arr2.Sort() ;// important as both array has to be sorted 

      for(int i=0;i<Arr1.Length ; i++)
         {
           if(Arr[i]!=Arr1[i])
              break;
         }

  }
```

Comment: That assumes the arrays are unordered.

Comment: @Brian : i did sort the array in  else as first step , ya i don't know if Mono has Sort method or not

Comment: That's my point. In your implementation { 1, 2 } and { 2, 1 } are equal, but this may not be the intended behavior. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

heres an efficient extension method that should do the trick

```
public static bool Compare<T>(this T[] source, T[] target, 
       Func<T,T,bool> comparer )
{
    if (source.Length != target.Length)
        return false;
    return !source.Where((t, i) => !comparer(t, target[i])).Any();
}

var a = new[] {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
var b = new[] {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
var c = new[] {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
var d = new[] {2, 4, 3, 5, 6, 8, 7};

var r1 = a.Compare(b, (i1, i2) => i1 == i2); // true
var r2 = a.Compare(c, (i1, i2) => i1 == i2); // false
var r3 = a.Compare(d, (i1, i2) => i1 == i2); // false
```

Comment: If LINQ is supported, you can simply use `SequenceEqual`.

Comment: @Danny - if the two sources are arrays and of unequal length, then my implementation will be faster as SequenceEquals only performs a comparison via a collections IEnumerable interface. Also, my implementation allows the user to provide a function that performas the comparison, whereas SequenceEquals tries to find the value of EqualityComparer<TSource>.Default - and if one doesnt exist in its cache it creates one using reflection, which may be a performance issue.

Comment: I mean the `.Where().Any` part in your code can be simply `SequenceEqual`, in which you can also provide a custom `Comparer`.