# c# filter a list of double[] values

Tags: c#, linq, list, filter

DESCRIPTION OF THE PROBLEM:

I have a list of double[] values representing vectors, where the 0th vector element correspond to the physical length of the vector and the other three (1 to 3) correspond to x, y, and z component. The list contains about 1000000 entries. So perfermonce would be an issue. I ordered the list according to the length of the vectors. Now I need to filter the list such that vectors of different length remain AND if the length is same filter those containing different entries (not permuatations) on position 1 to 3 remain as indicated in the example. Please let me know if you need more info.
The vectors should not be altered during the filtering process.

QUESTION: How can this be implemented using C# and if possible linq?

EXAMPLE:

```
 0,    0,     0;      0,0000   ->   select 
 0,    1,    -1;      8,2883   ->   select
 1,    0,    -1;      8,2883   ->   not select
 0,   -1,     1;      8,2883   ->   not select
-1,    0,     1;      8,2883   ->   not select
 1,   -1,     0;      8,2883   ->   not select
-1,    1,     0;      8,2883   ->   not select
 1,    1,    -2;     14,3558   ->   select
...
 2,     2,    -5;    38,6145   ->   select
-2,    -2,     5;    38,6145   ->   not select
 1,     4,    -4;    38,6145   ->   select
 4,     1,    -4;    38,6145   ->   not select
-1,    -4,     4;    38,6145   ->   not select
-4,    -1,     4;    38,6145   ->   not select
-1,     4,    -4;    38,6145   ->   not select
 4,    -1,    -4;    38,6145   ->   not select
-4,     1,     4;    38,6145   ->   not select
 1,    -4,     4;    38,6145   ->   not select
-2,     5,    -2;    38,6145   ->   not select
 5,    -2,    -2;    38,6145   ->   not select
 2,    -5,     2;    38,6145   ->   not select
-5,     2,     2;    38,6145   ->   not select
 4,    -4,    -1;    38,6145   ->   not select
-4,     4,    -1;    38,6145   ->   not select
-4,     4,     1;    38,6145   ->   not select
 4,    -4,     1;    38,6145   ->   not select
...
```

CODE:

```
private static double absm = 0;
private static int[] m = new int[3];
private static int[] m2 = new int[3];
private static List<double[]> ihkl1 = new List<double[]>();
private static List<double[]> ihkl2 = new List<double[]>();

...

private static void init_latt()
{
    for (int i = -kmax[2]; i < kmax[2]; i++ )
    {
        m[2] = i;
        for (int j = -kmax[1]; j < kmax[1]; j++)
        {
            m[1] = j;
            for (int k = -kmax[0]; k < kmax[0]; k++)
            {                        
                m[0] = k;
                absm = calcabsm(metten, m);                                             
                if (absm < gmax)
                {
                    double[] row1 = new double[4];
                    row1[0] = absm;
                    row1[1] = (double)m[0];
                    row1[2] = (double)m[1];
                    row1[3] = (double)m[2];
                    ihkl1.Add(row1);
                }
            }
        }
    }    
    ihkl2 = ihkl1.AsParallel().OrderBy(x => x[0]).ToList();
}
...
```

Comment: First suggestion: change from a `List<double[]>` to a `List<Vector>` where `Vector` is an appropriate encapsulation of the four values. Your code will be *much* clearer that way.

Comment: [What have you tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? Where are you stuck? Please post your current code and explain where it falls short.

Comment: You could consider FSharp if performance is an issue.

Comment: Enumerable.Distinct for such a large list may cause performance issues. Then again, it seems the list might have already been sorted... which itself is surely going to cause issues if performance is critical.

Comment: I suggest to use `for` loop for filtering if performance really matters. If maintenance and readability matters, then create `Vector` objects with properties `Length, X, Y, Z` and use LINQ to filter them.

Comment: Answering this would be a lot easier when you provide the declarations of the data structures involved.

Comment: I can filter vectors of different length, but I can not filter those having same length but different indices.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: You mean something like this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17425/A-Vector-Type-for-C

Comment: Well possibly, but you appear to have extra data in there (the length).

Comment: Well, the length is just needed for sorting it does not necessarily have to join the list containing the vector components.

Comment: I revised the code replacing the double[] arrays by using Microsoft's Vector3D class. This is of benefit because the length does not need to enter as a list column for sorting. However, I need to remove the permutations. I found something (http://stackoverflow.com/a/2913406) but unfortunately it's not working for Vector3D yet. Can you provide me any advice, please?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I agree with [Jon Skeet's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) suggestion of using a class `Vector` which encapsulates those `double` arrays. After that you can do:

```
public class VectorEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Vector>
{
    public bool Equals(Vector x, Vector y)
    {
        //here you implement the equality among vectors you defined in your question
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Vector obj)
    {
        //you can return something like obj.InnerArray.GetHashCode()
    }
}
```

Now, if you have a list of `Vector`, namely `yourList`, you can call:

```
var result = yourList.Distinct(new VectorEqualityComparer());
```

Hope this helps you achieve what you want. Good luck!!!

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try...if have further questions, I will post them here